# how many users logged on the computer

Tags: windows, switch-user

Suppose there are multiples users currently logged on on Windows. Say, user1 logs on, then switch user and user2 logs on, (without making user1 log off). I want to create a script that runs in the background all the time that does a full restart right after the fifth user did a 'switch user'.

Which language should I use, and how would I even start doing that?

Comment: Powershell would be the language I'd recommend.

Comment: Uh ... you realize this may cause users to lose data?

Comment: Of course- I work at a hospital, where most people log in to update some info about patient and then they just go away and so the same thing on a computer closest to the next patient. I want to make sure there aren't too many users connected at once.